# Where is the `peer_count` function?

Tags: rpc

I can't find the `net::*` RPC APIs under https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/be259234bfee056bef970ac372e04a74411c5224/client/rpc-api.

There are three net APIs, `netListening`, `netPeerCount` and `netVersion`.

I'm curious about where they were defined.

I can find all the other RPC APIs under that folder.

Comment: I'm confused, why do you think that these apis exist?

Comment: I could curl this. Also, I could use `polkadotapps -  rpc calls - net` send this.

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fdarwiniacrab-rpc.dwellir.com#/rpc

Maybe my chain's Substrate is too old? it's at `polkadot-v0.9.16`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, @bkchr. His comment inspires me.

I found this is a frontier RPC component.

https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/eef5723675850166da904b295b7dfa90894b1270/client/rpc-core/src/net.rs#L25-L40